# replace $ with £ using sed command

Tags: sed, special-characters

I have text file DollarToPound.txt with some Dollar signs ($)
please provide a shell script to replace dollar symbol with Pound(£) with sed command.

iam getting command garbled error!!!

please help.
Operating system used-- solaris 10